# IdentityNotFound Error in Amazon AWS Cognito Identity Sign In Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Hey guys am new to Xamarin Forms and AWS. I have created an App's Login Page but whenever i try to login i get "Identity 'us-east1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' not found error. I don't know what is the reason for this error. I tried creating User Pool and Identity Pool in different Region too but no luck. I am struck at this point. If anyone could help me it would be great.

MainWindow.xaml.cs file looks like this:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;
using System;

namespace YouBook
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainWindow : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly static string poolId = "us-east-1:edxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private readonly static string accountId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private readonly static string unAuthArn = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private readonly static string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private readonly static CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(accountId, poolId, unAuthArn, null, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        private readonly AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient _client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        private void SignUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SignUp signUpDlg = new SignUp(_client);
            //signUpDlg.ShowDialog();
            App.Current.MainPage = new SignUp(_client);
        }
        private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool loggedIn = await CheckPasswordAsync(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text);
            if (loggedIn == true)
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage();
            else
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Couldn't Login. Please Try Again!", "OK");
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var authReq = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                {
                    UserPoolId = poolId,
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
                };
                authReq.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", userName);
                authReq.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);

                AdminInitiateAuthResponse authResp = await _client.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(authReq);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Couldn't Login. " + ex.Message, "OK");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/114643/how-to-user-aws-cognito-to-sign-in-and-sign-up-users